# Draw a d3 graph of dots using something like d3.line.defined()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to draw a d3 line graph showing dots for the data points, as in [Adding dots to D3.js graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38235240/adding-dots-to-d3-js-graph) .  But I want to use a function like d3.line.defined() to define certain data values as ungraphable.

That will work for the line graphs, obviously, but how do I do it for the circles that are going to be drawn for the "dots"?  Maybe this is just simple, but I don't quite get how to do it.  Maybe it is a matter of filtering the data array.

Comment: You should consider filtering your data source before drawing it. But maybe you should also post some code in your question.

Comment: Part of the point of my visualization is to show when data is available and when it is not.

Answer (score 0):

My instinct does seem to work.
Thus if my line graph is

```
var line = d3.line()
    .defined(isdefined)  
    .x(function (d) {
        return x(d.xVal);
    })
    .y(function (d) {
        return y(d.yVal);
    })
   .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);

var svg = d3.select("body")
   .append("svg")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height)
   .append("g");
svg.append("path")
   .attr("d", line(data));
```

Then I can add "dots" (circles) at the data points, using the same function (isDefined) to determine valid data

```
svgG.selectAll('circle')
    .data(data.filter(isdefined))
    .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('r', 5)
    .attr('cx', function(d) {
        return x(d.xVal);'
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d) {
        return y(d.yVal);'
    })
```

See a working example in this codepen: https://codepen.io/hrabinowitz/pen/rqNBxg